# Negative values returned from pmvnorm in R, for multivariate normal integration

Tags: maximum-likelihood, numerical-integration

I'm using `pmvnorm` to obtain triple integration for multivariate normal density function in R. The integration range is from negative infinity to finite numbers for all three variables. However, occasionally the function returns with a negative value which makes no sense. I've looked at other posts where people suggested replacing the value with zero or increasing the precision of the algorithm.

These do not work in my case, however. After obtaining the probability from `pmvnorm`, say x, I need to transform it to log(x) to perform maximum likelihood estimation. So I can't simply replace negative x with a zero. Is there any other solution to this matter?

Comment: Can I simply replace -Inf with some value such as -100 in the normal density case where mean is no larger than 10 and variance/covariance is no larger than 10 as well?

Comment: You should give specific examples of this occurring, and then report them to the R package maintainers!

Comment: The MLE for a multivariate normal distribution is well-known and doesn't require maximizing a log-likelihood numerically.   What are (were) you actually trying to do?